# I’m trying to figure out how to create a command

Tags: mysql

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Your path to snames here/snames.csv'
INTO TABLE students
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(lname, fname, middle);

I’m trying to figure out what value is used for the middle field when there is no middle name/initial?  Im trying write a SELECT statement that will select only those students who do not have a middle name/initial.

Comment: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is not standard SQL.  You should probably update the tags on this question to accurately reflect which SQL server product you're asking about.

Comment: @JimDennis  `LOAD DATA INFILE` is MySQL command : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: @TASHA.SAKURA add `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` and `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'` after `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','` to include any empty strings in the CVS. Also before import,  you can set the default value of lname, fname, middle columns as NULL (table configuration ALTER). So, if you imported an empty strings it'll be converted to NULL in your table, then you can SELECT all NULL fields from your table.

Comment: @ISR5 and my point remains: the question should be properly tagged (which I have now done).

Comment: Sorry it’s my first time being on here so I wasn’t sure on what to tag

Comment: I am a little disappointed that you deleted your interesting other question.

Comment: yeah im sorry i felt i didnt explain my question well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use id 'IS NULL' in select statement:
`SELECT * FROM students WHERE middle Is NULL`

Comment: Thank you I’ll try to see if that filters out the data.

Comment: @TASHA.SAKURA, please accept the answer, if it has worked for you.

Comment: I tried it works but it’s not doing what I want it just gives me a blank table I’m trying filter out the students who don’t have middle names so it should result in showing students who do not have middle names

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming MS SQL is the DBMS. ISNULL will allow for Nulls plus empty strings. It is just a null replacement. If the field is an integer field it works as follows ISNULL(Myfield,0). NULL's always seem to produce gotcha's in your select statements. You need to wrap your head around them. Cheers

```
SELECT lname, fname, middle
FROM Students
WHERE ISNULL(middle,'') <> ''
```

Comment: Sia used "IS NULL" to select directly on the field. This is different to ISNULL() function I used to select indirectly on an empty string. There are multiple syntax's around NULL handling and you have to be a bit careful.